# ssh tunneled command output to file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have an old Syno NAS and wish to use the "shred" command to wipe this disks inside. The idea is to let the command run to complete on the box itself without the need of a computer.

So far I have managed...
1) to get the right parameters for 'shred'
* runs in the background using the &
2) get that command to output the progress (-v option) to a file shred.txt
* to see from the file what the progress is

`shred -v -f -z -n 2 /dev/hdd 2>&1 | tee /volume1/backup/shred.txt &`

3) ssh tunnel the command so I can turn off my laptop while its running

`ssh -n -f root@host "sh -c 'nohup /opt/bin/shred -f -z -n 2 /dev/sdd > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"`

The problem is that I can't combine 2) and 3)
I tried to combine them like this, but the resulting file remained empty:

`ssh -n -f root@host "sh -c 'nohup /opt/bin/shred -f -z -n 2 /dev/sdd 2>&1 | tee /volume1/backup/shred.txt > /dev/null &'"`

It might be a case of the NOOBS but I can't figure out how to get this done.

Any suggestions?

Thanks. Vince

Comment: SIGH How come I mention in my post the -v option to output and not put in the final command:

`ssh -n -f root@host "sh -c 'nohup /opt/bin/shred -f -v -z -n 2 /dev/sdd 2>&1 | tee /volume1/backup/shred.txt > /dev/null &'"`

All working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Commands `sh` and `tee` are not needed in here:

```
ssh -n root@host 'nohup /opt/bin/shred -f -z -n 2 /dev/sdd 2>&1 >/volume1/backup/shred.txt &' >/dev/null
```

The final `>/dev/null` is optional, it will just disregard any greetings from other hosts.

Comment: @bigvince I fixed it a little more.

Comment: awesome! I just made sure I added the -v in there as well... Thanks mate

Comment: Another question Grzegorz... I have been trying to include a date at the start (date > shred.txt; <<rest of command>>) which works fine. Any idea how I can include the same type of code at the end? The problem I can't seem to figure out is where to put the "&" to run the shred command in the background and still let the date stamp be added to the log file when the commands has been completed. In the end I want to see when the process started and when it finished.

Comment: @bigvince Please make it a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following command (based on Grzegorz suggestion) and included the opening date stamp and the before mentioned - stupidly forgotten - verbose switch. Last version of the command string:

`ssh -n root@host 'date > /volume1/backup/shred_sda.txt; nohup /opt/bin/shred -v -f -z -n 4 /dev/sda 2>&1 >> /volume1/backup/shred_sda.txt @ >/dev/null'`

The last thing to figure out is how to include the date stamp when the shred command has completed.